# iOS Dev - How to detect that user gets to this UIViewController by pressing "Back"

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, key, back

I have an iOS app with 3 tabs:

- Home
- Tab1
- Tab2

In "Home", user can navigate to a view - `UIViewcontroller1` - to view the details. When the user pressed "Back" in `UIViewcontroller1` to go back to "Home", I would like to detect in Home `viewDidLoad()` that the user came here by pressing "Back" in `UIViewcontroller1`.

Is there a simple way to detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of a couple of ways to do this, none of them is exactly what you want but they might work.

First, you can detect the back on `UIViewController1`'s `viewWillDisappear`, like this:

```
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound) {
    //Do what you want to do here
}
```

Second, you could make Home `UIViewController1`'s delegate and call whatever method you want.

Third, you could set a variable when Home pushes `UIViewController1` onto the stack and check it on `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 2):

A delegation pattern could solve that issue.

You should have a look at this post:

[Passing data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)